# Query data in user context in Lightning Web Component (LWC) for proper picklist value translation

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, localization

I created a *Lightning Web Componentent* (LWC) in Salesforce to view a *lightning-datatable* of **Contact** objects, queried from the list of **Contacts** assigned to an **Account** object, including the `LastName` and `Salutation` fields.

I am testing this with two different users, one with platform default *english* language settings, the other one with *german* language settings.

If a list of **Contact** objects is shown in the Salesforce standard **Contacts** tab, the english user sees `Salutation` values *Mr.* and *Ms.* while the german user sees *Herr* and *Frau* (see Screenshot 1).

In the LWC the data seems to be queried in system context instead of user context, since the result is always shown in english language, i.e. for the `Salutation` showing *Mr.* and *Ms.* (see Screenshot 2).

How can I achieve that the shown data is queried in proper user context to auto-translate the `Salutation` field?

---

## Screenshots

#### Screenshot 1

View of contacts in Salesforce Contact object list view (english user left, german user right)
[image: View of contacts in Salesforce Contact object list view (english user left, german user right)]

#### Screenshot 2

View of contacts in custom Lightning Web Component (english user left, german user right)
[image: View of contacts in custom Lightning Web Component (english user left, german user right)]

---

## Minimal Working Example (MWE)

### Lightning Web Component

#### HTML markup

mWEQueryUserContext.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field='Id'
        data={tableData}
        columns={tableColumns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

#### Javascript controller

mWEQueryUserContext.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/MWEQueryUserContextController.getContacts';

export default class MWEQueryUserContext extends LightningElement {

    @track accountId = '0015t00001HIPLTQ'; // arbitrary accountId for testing
    @track tableData = [];

    @wire(getContacts, {accountId: "$accountId"})
    wiredContactsOfAccount({error, data}){
        if(data == null) return;
        this.tableData = data;
    }  

    get tableColumns() {
        return [
            {label: 'Salutation', fieldName: 'Salutation'},
            {label: 'LastName',   fieldName: 'LastName'}
      ];
    }
}
```

### Apex controller

MWEQueryUserContextController.cls

```
public with sharing class MWEQueryUserContextController {
    public MWEQueryUserContextController() {}
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(String accountId) {
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        if(String.isBlank(accountId)) return contactList; //empty list
        contactList = [
            SELECT
                Id,
                Salutation,
                LastName
            FROM
                Contact
            WHERE
                AccountId = :accountId
        ];
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex always uses the "API" value by default. Use `toLabel` to get the UI value, as in:

```
public class MWEQueryUserContextController {
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(String accountId) {
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        if(String.isBlank(accountId)) return contactList; //empty list
        contactList = [
            SELECT
                Id,
                toLabel(Salutation),
                LastName
            FROM
                Contact
            WHERE
                AccountId = :accountId
        ];
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

Or, use [`getPicklistValuesByRecordType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-picklist-values-record.html) in LWC to get the picklist values.

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, {
  objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT,
  recordTypeId: "012000000000000AAA",
}) accountPicklistValues;
@track accountId = '0015t00001HIPLTQ'; // arbitrary accountId for testing
@track tableData = [];
@wire(getContacts, {accountId: "$accountId" })
  async wiredContactsOfAccount({error, data}){
    if(data) {
      await Promise.resolve(); // make sure account picklist values are loaded
      this.tableData = data.map((record) => ({ 
        ...record, 
        Salutation: this.accountPicklistValues.data.picklistFieldValues
  .Salutation.values.find((entry) => entry.value === record.Salutation)?.label }));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Changing the `Salutation` field to `toLabel(Salutation)` in the select statement in my Apex controller did the trick. Thanks for the simple solution.